# Modx placing placeholders after ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, modx-revolution

I've the page, which loads content by click on the button from user database via jquery ajax.

File, which handles ajax request, has this code:

```
return $modx->runSnippet('pdoPage',array( 
   'class' => 'LibraryContent',
   'tpl' => 'tpl.lib-main',
   'element' => 'Ajax_test'
));
```

Sender of request receives answer, snippet works ok, I see data, which snippet returns. But, what about placeholders? For example, I want use pagination by this snippet(pdoPage). I cannot send placeholders via ajax, because modx parser have been worked and placeholder will be a plain text. Other path is paste placeholder to resource, which send ajax request, but no way — there is placeholder, but there is no results of pdoPage's work. Finally, placeholder is empty.

So, my question is how to "alive" placeholder for snippet, which loads by ajax request?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1'st way:

```
$output = $modx->runSnippet('pdoPage',array( 
   'class' => 'LibraryContent',
   'tpl' => 'tpl.lib-main',
   'element' => 'Ajax_test'
));
$pagination = $modx->getPlaceholder('page.nav');
return $output.$pagination;
```

2'nd way:

```
$content = $modx->runSnippet('pdoPage',array( 
   'class' => 'LibraryContent',
   'tpl' => 'tpl.lib-main',
   'element' => 'Ajax_test'
));
$pagination = $modx->getPlaceholder('page.nav');
$output = array(
    'content' => $content, 
    'pagination' => $pagination
);
return $modx->toJSON($output);
```